# ueye package error

Tags: ros, ueye-cam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I install the driver and ros package successfully but when I launch this commande:

```
>$ roslaunch ueye_cam bayer_rggb_image_proc.launch
```

I got this error:

```
[bayer_rggb_image_proc.launch] is neither a launch file in package [ueye_cam] nor is [ueye_cam] a launch file name
```

What's going wrong ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/173369/ueye-package-error/) by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) on ROS Answers with karma: 751 on 2014-06-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'll answer myself :D so that's how can everybody look at the solution
Just type this everytime you open a new shell:

```
$>cd /home/<name>/catkin_ws
$>source devel/setup.bash
```

---

Originally posted by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) with karma: 751 on 2014-06-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ricardoej](https://answers.ros.org/users/13141/ricardoej/) on 2014-06-11**:
Or you can add it to your .bashrc file as follows:

echo "source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash" >> ~/.bashrc

This way, every time you open your terminal the command "source ..." will run.

**Comment by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) on 2014-06-11**:
I tried to do that but it doesn't work
what I did is

> $ cd
> >$ gedit ~/.bashrc
> and then I add this line <source devel/setup.bash> on the file at the end and I save it.
> I don't know if do it right !?

**Comment by [ricardoej](https://answers.ros.org/users/13141/ricardoej/) on 2014-06-11**:
So just gedit the ~/.bashrc file and add the follow two lines at the end: source /opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash and source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash

**Comment by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) on 2014-06-12**:
Yes, It works now Thank you so much